# C to Python interface - Trying to pass structs

Tags: python, c, struct, interface, segmentation-fault

I'm currently working on an interface between C and Python and I detected a problem I'm not able to solve: I want to pass a struct to Python. Sounds simple, but somehow I keep getting a SegFault. I already prepared everything so that the object which is returned is usable from Python. If I create an instance of it in Python it works just fine but I somehow can't use it when it is returned from a function. Here's the corresponding code:

```
typedef struct{
    PyObject_HEAD
    op *grid;
    double beta, *umatrix, *energies, weight;
    int nflavours, opCount;

} SegmentTrace;


typedef struct{
    PyObject_HEAD
    double ratio;
} SegInsert;


static PyObject *segTr_insert(SegmentTrace *self, PyObject *args)
{
    SegInsert *res = (SegInsert*)malloc(sizeof(SegInsert));
    return Py_BuildValue("O", (PyObject*)res);
}
```

With these definitions (and the corresponding Type definitions) I'm able to do the following:

```
import cs

obj_1 = cs.segmentTrace(0., mat_a, mat_b)
obj_2 = cs.segInsert()

print obj_2.ratio
```

but not:

```
import cs

obj_1 = cs.segmentTrace(0., mat_a, mat_b)
obj_3 = obj_1.insert()

print obj_3.ratio
```

For some reason a SegFault is popping up - does anybody know why?

Thanks,
lukas.

Comment: Building the object this way is quite convenient, since there already exists a code in which I want to "plug in" this object without changing anything. Everything works fine except for this - Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out - at least a workaround which will do the trick. Anyway, just for the sake of completeness: It is possible to pass the self-created Python-C-Objects out of Python to some C-routines and use the data there. That is, instead of

```
obj_1 = cs.segmentTrace(0., mat_a, mat_b)
obj_3 = obj_1.insert()
```

use:

```
obj_1 = cs.segmentTrace(0., mat_a, mat_b)
obj_3 = cs.segInsert(obj)
```

Works just fine ;)
L.